# VBA - Partially renaming Excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, file-rename

I need help regarding renaming excel files partially. I have about 40 of these in a folder which needs partial renaming every month.

The files are saved like:
06.01.2022 - 06.30.2022 - 1458 - ABCD 
06.01.2022 - 06.30.2022 - 2579 - EFGH

and I need only the month to be changed like:
07.01.2022 - 07.31.2022 - 1458 - ABCD
07.01.2022 - 07.31.2022 - 2579 - EFGH

I have been trying to use the code below but it is bringing Run-Time error as file not found. I tried looking online but every VBA code seems to change the name entirely . I want the files to have their respective file name and be successful in partially renaming them. Can you please help me?

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

```
Sub ReNaming()

Dim xlFile As Variant
Dim nFile As String

xlFile = Dir("C:\Test\*.xls*") '/* Folder that contains the files */

Do While xlFile <> "" '/* check if anything is returned */
    If InStr(xlFile, "06.01.2022 - 06.30.2022") <> 0 Then '/* check if there is 'QFR' in the filename
        nFile = VBA.Replace(xlFile, "06.01.2022 - 06.30.2022", "07.01.2022 - 07.31.2022") '/* replace if there is */
        Name xlFile As nFile '/* rename the file */
    End If
    xlFile = Dir '/* Test for more */
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Pass the full path to `Name`, not just the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the full path like below

```
Public Sub runthis()

Dim xlFile As Variant
Dim nFile As String
Dim directory As String

directory = "C:\Test\"
xlFile = Dir(directory & "*.xls") '/* Folder that contains the files */

Do While xlFile <> "" '/* check if anything is returned */
    If InStr(xlFile, "06.01.2022 - 06.30.2022") <> 0 Then '/* check if there is 'QFR' in the filename
        nFile = VBA.Replace(xlFile, xlFile, "1" & xlFile) '/* replace if there is */
        Name directory & xlFile As directory & nFile '/* rename the file */
    End If
    xlFile = Dir '/* Test for more */
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Aldert, using your code just added 1 in front of the file name, i need to replace the date. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Yes for sure it did as I understood the problem was with the file not found so I mae a small test. Let me look at it a bit further, hold on..

Comment: So put your VBA.replace line back in and you are good?

Comment: You are welcome: Please mark question as answered